# Uploading Information to a database with a disabled textbox

Tags: php, html, database, text

I have  form that has 2 radio buttons(Yes and No) and a text box. If the user clicks Yes it enables the text box you can input information and it is uploaded to the database including the value from the radio buttons. If you click no it disables the text box and suppose to upload the value of the radio box only to  the database. But I am not getting that.

```
<input type="radio" name="TermLease" value="No" onclick="TermLeaseMonths.disabled=true">No
<input type="radio" name="TermLease" value="Yes"  onclick="TermLeaseMonths.disabled=false">Yes | 
How many months:<input type="hidden" name="TermLeaseMonths"  value="0" />
<input type="text" name="TermLeaseMonths" id="TermLeaseMonths" size="1" disabled="true">
```

I have a hidden input type that uploads the value. But when I click yes it does not disable the text box. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: JavaScript, jQuery, asp.net, MVC, PHP, Python, something to save to a database.  Let me know what you are using so I can help you.

Comment: php is the language I am using

Comment: will u explain it more r u trying to acess the values of disabled textbox on click

Comment: for disabling a text box use this $('#test1').attr('disabled', true);

Comment: When I click yes It uploads Value="yes" and whatever is in the text box and when i click no it suppose to upload Value="No" and 0 for the text box. But When I click Yes text box is still disabled its supposed to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot give id for the text field. Try this

```
<input type="radio" name="TermLease" value="No" onclick="TermLeaseMonths.disabled=true">No
<input type="radio" name="TermLease" value="Yes"  onclick="TermLeaseMonths.disabled=false">Yes | 
How many months:<input type="hidden" name="TermLeaseMonths"  value="0" />
<input type="text" name="TermLeaseMonths" id="TermLeaseMonths" size="1" disabled="true">
```

Comment: I tired that and that also did not work the text box is still disabled when I click yes

Comment: Have you really added id for the textbox ? its working for me

Comment: I have edited my answer, replace your code with this and let me know is it working or not

Comment: What I did in your code, I have just added a id in textbox "TermLeaseMonths" and its working for me. I can't find any other issue with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on click of radio button we can do by this way

```
$('#radio').click(function () {
    if (("#radio").val() == "") {
        $('class_name_oftextBox').attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $('class_name_oftextBox').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Or you can do this as

```
$('#enable').click(function () {
    $('#textBox').removeAttr("disabled")
});
$('#disable').click(function () {
    $('#textBox').attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

Comment: This is javascript i am assuming?

Comment: @patgarci the above is jQuery which you didn't say you were using, if you are let me know.

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/FXrQ3/)

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <span style="float: left;">
        <label><input type="radio" name="TermLease" value="No" onclick="ShowHideTextbox('leaseMonths', false)" />No</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="TermLease" value="Yes"  onclick="ShowHideTextbox('leaseMonths', true)"/>Yes</label>
    </span>

    <span id="leaseMonths" style="display: none; float: left;">
        <span> | </span>  <span>How many months: </span>
        <input type="text" name="TermLeaseMonths" id="TermLeaseMonths" size="1" />
    </span>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
var previousNumberOfMonths = "0";

function ShowHideTextbox(elementId, show) {
    var link = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var textbox = document.getElementById("TermLeaseMonths");
    if (show){    
        textbox.value = previousNumberOfMonths;

        link.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        link.style.display = 'none';
        previousNumberOfMonths = textbox.value;

        document.getElementById("TermLeaseMonths").value = "0";
    }
}
```